# Computers and Mobile Devices for Showcasing Software

Tags: website-design, stock-images, royalty-free

I am looking for an appealing way to showcase some of my existing software online. I noticed that a current trend is to show the software running on multiple devices, like this:

[image: From here: media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/736x/af/b0/ed/afb0ed0de200f13e6fd425f9937fa7e1.jpg]

[image: From here: www.admirhadzic.com/img/projects/weboxit/04/2400.jpg]

Does everyone who uses this design pattern really photograph their own images, or is there somewhere I can find pictures such as this, and drop my own images in as the "screens"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are hundreds of stock photographs like these for sale all over the web, [these](https://dealotto.com/deals/10-hip-apple-device-mock-ups/) being some of my personal favorites

If you just search for "device mockups" you should get a fair few results. There was a pack a while ago that was absolutely fantastic, that you only needed to drop your screenshot into a smart layer and it would adjust it to the device automatically: [50 Apple Devices MockUps](http://dealjumbo.com/50-apple-devices-mockups)